# Game function and blocked accept, socket c++

Tags: c++, sockets

people, the question I have this code:

```
if( listen( server_socket, 50 ) < 0 ) {
    perror( "listen" );
    exit( 1 );
}

while( 1 )
{
    size = sizeof( client_addr )
    client_socket = accept( server_socket, ( struct sockaddr * ) & client_addr, & size );

    connection.push_back( client_socket );
    GameStart( clients );
    clients++;

}
```

`GameStart();` - this function that receives / sends packets, works all the time until the client disconnects.

I have a question, when one client is connected, the second client blocked, and can't enter to the game, how to fix it? C:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `GameStart` in the new thread. Now execution cannot proceed after `GameStart()`.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;

while( 1 )
{
    size = sizeof( client_addr )
    client_socket = accept( server_socket, ( struct sockaddr * ) & client_addr, & size );

    connection.push_back( client_socket );

    std::thread th(GameStart, clients);
    threads.push_back(std::move(th));
    clients++;

}
```

And you should to join all threads back somewhere in your program.

```
for (auto& th : threads)
{
    th.join();
}
```

Comment: tbh, most likely other way around, because most of render systems  (with rare exceptions)  do not support maintaining contexts outside main thread

Comment: @Swift May be this is a MUD?